# Check multiple conditions in Ruby on Rails search using AND / OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My current method is as follows:

```
    def self.search(query)
     where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")
    end
```

How can I add additional attributes? For example, I can't get this to work but it shows what I want to do:

```
    def self.search(query)
     where("name like ? OR model like ? OR year like ?", "%#{query}%")
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers will both work, but it's easier in these cases to use named placeholders, because then you won't have to specify the query multiple times:

```
def self.search query
  where( "name LIKE :query OR model LIKE :query OR year LIKE :query", query: "%#{query}%")
end
```

#### Update

In the comments Stefan suggested using HEREDOC for a long query, which is a great suggestion. I'd like to also offer how I'd produce this particular string.

Because it's basically the same thing repeated three times, and then joined with `OR`s I'd actually create a little loop to construct the string, like so:

```
query_string = %w[name model year].map{|n| n+" LIKE :query"}.join(" OR ")
where( query_string, query: )
```

That way if I want to add another field later then it's much simpler.

Comment: Note that you can use a heredoc to write long queries on multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you want to do this:

```
def self.search(query)
  where("name like ? OR model like ? OR year like ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
end
```

If you are using `like` all the three fields must be strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think answer closes to your question is:

  `def self.search(name,model)
    where [ "name like ? OR model like ?" , name, model] 
  end`

Comment: The "query" that was in the original method is based on input into a text_field. Basically I want to check the text field against all of the attributes as a person may put in name, make model, etc...