# Issuing a query with Rails using OR operator with dynamic params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the best way to issue a query with an "OR" operator with dynamic params within Rails? I have a simple API that checks whether the user wants to search in certain categories.

```
categories = params[:categories].split(',')
```

I want to make a query that seems like this

```
category_1 = 1 OR category_2 = 1 OR ...
```

I currently build a string iterating through categories and issue

```
@resource = Resource.where(query)
```

Is this the best way to make a query of this type?

Comment: There's `arel` and `squeel` that can help you write a query you want and keep the compatibility benefits of ActiveRecord. You should already have `arel` as AR's dependency, try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"best" doesn't really mean much here, different methods have their pros and cons. There's certainly nothing wrong with doing what you're doing (in fact I recommended essentially this method [earlier today here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158487/152786))